# What is preferable : detecting device using its size or user agent string?

Tags: java, android, iphone, device, browser-detection

I need to differentiate between mobile/tablet and desktop browsers and i was wondering is it better to parse user agent string or look at width and height of the device to determine same? Which method is preferable and why?

TIA

Comment: "I need to differentiate between mobile/tablet and desktop browsers" -- what specifically are you looking to do differently?

Comment: I need to send info to a third party on what device (mobile or tablet or desktop) is user viewing our web page.

Comment: are you detect device from android app or website ?

Comment: Then *ask the third party* what you should be doing. After all, what *we* think the right answer is may not match what *they* think the right answer is, and what they want is what should matter to you.

Comment: hi julien, we need to detect device accessing our website

Answer (score 1):

You typically need to do both.  The User Agent isn't enough to distinguish between android phones and tablets.

See this link on how Google Web Toolkit does it:
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp/src/com/google/gwt/sample/mobilewebapp/FormFactor.gwt.xml?r=10041

Basically, you check the useragent for "iphone" or "ipad", else check for "android" (if so, use the size to determine mobile/tablet), otherwise it's a "desktop".

Answer (score 0):

Is this information directly used by your application, or is it used by business/marketing to figure who is looking at your site?  If it is a marketing need, then you should use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), you simply embed a piece of code into your HTML and your business folks will get ALL the info they'd ever want about visitor's devices, browsing patterns, drop off pages, flows, etc.